# two texts overlapping each other when resizing window

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML and CSS code below

```css
.hero{
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, #e8922d .11%, #eca757 127.33%);
  overflow: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  box-shadow: 3px 2px 3px #f1bd81;
}

.my-auto{
  color: #FFFFFF80;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: .4px;
  mix-blend-mode: normal;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.price_chart{
  color: #FFFFFF80;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: -38px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header" class="hero">
  <div class="dogeNav">
  <span class="my-auto">
  YOUR WALLET</span>
  </div>

  <div class="price_chart">
  <p>current price - $0.05</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is div header. "my-auto" class is in the center of div. "price-chart" is on the right side of div. Problem is when I resize my window two of the texts overlap each other, how could I fix that.

Comment: Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [<>] snippet editor.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understood your question completely but I've made some changes on your code.
I hope this what you want.

```css
.hero{
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, #e8922d .11%, #eca757 127.33%);
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  box-shadow: 3px 2px 3px #f1bd81;
}

.my-auto{
  color: #FFFFFF80;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: .4px;
  mix-blend-mode: normal;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.price_chart{
  color: #FFFFFF;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: -38px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header" class="hero">
  <div class="dogeNav">
  <span class="my-auto">
  YOUR WALLET</span>
    <div class="price_chart">
  <p>current price - $0.05</p>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Codepen.io](https://codepen.io/lucassaladini/pen/ExNbqXR)